# How to get an instance of javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry with proper scope

Tags: java, awt, websphere, javax.imageio

We have several webapps deployed to a WebSphere application server, where both applications use the ImageIO of standard Java, but one uses an additional Library to add more Readers/Writers.

The question is now, both applications use `IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance()` to get the instance of the service registry, and both applications seem to get the same instance. Internally this is related to `AppContext.getAppContext()` returning the same awt AppContext. Is there any proper way to have multiple WebSphere Applications using ImageIO of Java without having to care about both apps using the same libraries?
Do I have to manually create an awt AppContext for my WebSphere Applications?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the app context concept (the one used in the `IIORegistry` class, not to be confused with a web app context) was originally intended for applets (ie., multiple applets running in a single JVM in a browser). For web apps, this would also make sense, but I don't think it works that way. Also, I don't think there are any public API classes or methods related to creating or maintaining app contexts (it's all in the `sun.awt.*` packages), so manually creating contexts isn't recommended.

I've made a [web context listener](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app) that will solve some of the issues with using `ImageIO` in web apps, ie. registering and unregistering web app "local" plugins, when the web app is loaded/unloaded (handling both discovery and removal of "stale" plugins). Unfortunately, this will not hide on web app's plugins from other web apps, if this is your intention (hard to tell from the question).

Having an `AppContext` per web app would probably be a cleaner approach, but as mentioned, the lack of public API and no "standard" way of doing it would make such a solution non-portable and thus undesirable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and indeed, the intention would be to hide the plugins of one web app from the other. Undesired NoClassDefFoundErrors are preventing the other side from working properly, so either both webapps have to share the same set of libraries (feasible but somehow strange) or there has to be some way to hide a second webapp from another in some way.

Comment: @ThomasW I think the easiest way to achieve this, is simply running multiple WebSphere instances, one for each web application.

Comment: @ThomasW Come to think of it, it might be possible within the same container. But it requires some way to configure WebSphere to use a `ThreadGroup` per web app context. I'm not sure if that's possible? In any case, I wrote a quick PoC to prove that different thread groups actually do get different `IIORegistry` instances as documented.

Comment: My current idea would be to force a Proxy of `IIORegistry` into the shared `AppContext` by forcefully overwriting it in a Custom IIORegistry, as the underlying storage seems to be a HashMap with no check whether the current Key is already in it. and when the Proxy gets called within a Webapp Context, that has an own instance of `IIORegistry` registered, use that one, and else the initially stored one. I am not 100% sure if that is a good idea, but sounds possible to me, or am I missing something?